# What is the formulation of $\sinh^{-1} x$?

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions

I am trying to formulate $\sinh^{-1} x$.

I know that $$\sinh x = \dfrac{\exp(x)-\exp(-x)}{2}$$

but how do we translate $\sinh^{-1} x$ ?

Please excuse my lack of knowledge in math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y=\operatorname{arsinh}x$ then $x=\sinh y=\frac{e^y-e^{-y}}{2}$, which rearranges to $e^{2y}-2xe^y-1=0$, a quadratic in $e^y=x\pm\sqrt{x^2+1}$. We need the $\pm=+$ branch because, when $y$ is large, $x\sim\tfrac12e^y$ (or even easier, note $e^y>0$). So $$\operatorname{arsinh}x=\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right).$$You can show as a similar exercise that$$\operatorname{arcosh}x=\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right),\,\operatorname{artanh}x=\tfrac12\ln\tfrac{1+x}{1-x}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your help and elaboration.

Comment: $x-\sqrt{x^2+1}$ is discarded because it is negative, for any $x$, while $e^y$ is positive.

Comment: Inverse hyperbolic are usually called ARCSINH, ARCCOSH and ARCTANH

Comment: @Raffaele Since the "Ar" [comes from "area"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions#Inverse_hyperbolic_sine) and not from "arcus", that naming, while not uncommon, is problematic.

Comment: Aww! I didn't know. Thank you for the explanation